# MongoDB $set operator. Trying to update an object inside array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a specific field in my MongoDB schema in my Node.js API.

Specifically, the function works to accept a friend request for a user (*the accepter*) The *friend* will be stored in the **friends** array, and when the user (*the accepter*) accepts the request, the status of the *friend* in the **friends** array will change from 'pending' to 'accepted'

From other similar posts, I understand that the $set operator allows me to find and edit inside the **friends** array, but the database does not update to "accepted." It seems none of the solutions work so far.

Additional Info:

- My HTTP Client hangs when I access the route
- My accepterID works (when I console.log, I am able to view the entire user object (*the accepter*)
- The requesterID also works

Any Help would be greatly appreciated! I am brand new to this!

Here is the function:

```
 User.findById(accepterID)
          .then(accepter => {
            accepter.update(
              { "friends.friendID" : requesterID }, 
              { $set: { "friends.$.status" : "accepted" }},
            )
            res.json(accepter)
          })
        }
```

Here is the Schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({

  method: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['local', 'google', 'facebook'],
    required: true
  },

  friends: [
    {
      status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['requested', 'pending', 'accepted']
      },
      addedWhen: {
        type: Date
      },
      friendID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      }
    }
  ],

  local: {
    firstName: {
      type: String
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying such an `update` gives me a deprecation warning (it seems `update` is an alias for the collection's `update`), then crashes because *"cannot use part (friends of friends.status) to traverse the element"*. Not sure why it says so.

So maybe your HTTP client hangs because somewhere you don't handle errors properly? (Anyway, no reason `res.json` fails on itself.)

Independently from this HTTP debugging of yours, I had the update working like this:

```
User.findById(accepterID).then(accepter => {
  // updateOne works as well, but no way it gives the fresh doc
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: accepterID, 'friends.friendID': requesterID },
    { $set: { friends.$.status: 'accepted' } },
    { new: true },
    (err, freshAccepter) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(freshAccepter);
    }
  );
});
```

Or shorter, since you don't need the original accepter, no need for the wrapping `findById`.